# Disadvantages of 32 bit mode

Tags: kernel

I have a Cisco VPN client in OSX 10.6.8, which runs only in 32 bit mode.

Are there any serious disadvantages of switching to 32 bit mode permanently?

Comment: Is the is the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client ? I'm running OS X 10.6.8 in full 64 bit mode with version 2.5.2006 of this client without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not inherently.  32 bit mode should run fine as long as all your drivers and binaries include a 32-bit version, which is currently the case unless you specifically downloaded 64-bit versions.  It should even use a little less ram.

But:

- Mountain Lion will be 64-bit only, so I don't expect universal binaries to include 32-bit versions forever.
- I have "slimmed" all my binaries to delete the 32-bit version.  If you have ever used such space-saving utilities, the slimmed apps won't work.

Comment: Are there any limitations as to Physical memory?

Comment: No, it will support whatever your hardware does.  ([More on the difference](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=783948))